# Creating a CPT(Custom Post Type)-like object (like Wordpress) in Shopify for easier retrieval in a section

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

Context: I'm trying to create a section that would render an accordion on the site that would list the individual member's names of a business team (ie. sales, marketing, etc), their title, an image of themselves, and possibly a URL that will take them to their individual member page. There could be multiple accordions in the page so I need to make these into blocks for easier rendering.

The obvious answer (at least to me), was to make a section utilizing a nested block design like so:

```
{% schema %}
    {
        "blocks": [
            "name": "Accordion"
            "settings": [
                {
                    "id": "accordion_name",
                    "type": "text",
                    "label": "Accordion Name"
                },
                {
                    "blocks": [

                    ]
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
{% endschema %}

{% stylesheet %}
{% endstylesheet %}

{% javascript %}
{% endjavascript %}
```

The problem is that you really can't do a nested block design in Shopify, so the next thing I thought was to create a CPT(Custom Post Type)-like object that would store these people for me (akin to Wordpress). And then after that, I can just import the data that these things have into my section as a collection (at least instead of a collection of products, it's a collection of people).

I'm just wondering if this is possible within Shopify's environment. I've been looking into trying to create my own app for this (with the last resort being to use an app on the store), but I don't want to spend time developing this app only to realize that it was never going to work in the first place.

If it is possible, I would like some hints, tricks, or resources that can point me in the right direction.

Please do mind that this is technically my first time using Shopify as a platform.

Thank you very much to anyone who would answer me.

EDIT: This kind of block structure is enclosed in a footer section.

Answer (score 0):

There are no custom post types in Shopify like the ones in WordPress. The closest thing is a blog, since you can have multiply blogs instead of a single one.

If you are going to use this on a single page you can go around using different block types.

So for example you can do something like this:

```
<div class="accordion">
  {%- for block in section.blocks -%}
    {%- assign _block = block.settings -%}
    {%- case block.type -%}

      {%- when 'heading' -%}
        {%- assign block_title = _block.title -%}

        {%- unless forloop.first -%}
          </div><!-- /.accordion -->
          <div class="accordion">
        {%- endunless -%}

        <div class="accordion__head">
          {{ block_title }}
        </div><!-- /.accordion__head -->

      {%- when 'member' -%}
        {%- assign block_title = _block.title -%}
        {%- assign block_image = _block.image -%}
        {%- assign block_link = _block.link -%}

        <div class="accordion__user">
          {{ block_image | img_url: '150x150' | img_tag }}
          <h4>{{ title }}</h4>
          <a href="{{block_link}}">Read more</a>
        </div><!-- /.accordion content -->
    {%- endcase -%}
  {%- endfor -%}
</div><!-- /.accordion -->

{% schema %}
{
  "name": "Accordion",
  "blocks": [
    {
      "type": "heading",
      "name": "Heading",
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "id": "title",
          "label": "Title"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "member",
      "name": "Member",
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "id": "title",
          "label": "Title"
        },
        {
          "type": "image_picker",
          "id": "image",
          "label": "Image"
        },
        {
          "type": "url",
          "id": "link",
          "label": "Link"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

Where you have 2 types of blocks, one for heading and one for the member.

You loop the blocks and when you have a heading you close and open the accordion `div` with the following code:

```
    {%- unless forloop.first -%}
      </div><!-- /.accordion -->
      <div class="accordion">
    {%- endunless -%}
```

There are other approaches but this is one of the most cleanest way for the administrator.

Comment: So building an app to make these objects globally accessible across different parts of the site is a no go?

Comment: @ace_01S If you fill a static section one time and call it on multiply locations it will be prefilled with the same content, so yes they will be globally available and there will be no need for an App. But if you need to use different content on different locations for the same section than you can't and it may require the use of some App.

Comment: The schema that you presented doesn't really represent any kind of grouping. I wanted for one accordion block to say Marketing Team for example, and inside that would be its members. The way that the schema is presented makes it look like I'm just adding sections without regards for categorization. In my opinion, that's kinda user unfriendly for clients and other people with regards to modifying the theme. Is there really no other way?

Comment: @ace_01S If you don't understand how the provided code works I can't help you since in fact it groups the blocks into accordions with heading and members into them. Look into accordion APPs if you think that will suit your needs better.

Comment: My concern is the Theme Customizer. The schema is rendered as a single **static** Accordion section with blocks that are either headings or members. It is rendered in the actual HTML as multiple accordions every time it hits a heading. That part I get.

But that's not intuitive through the user's perspective because it makes it look that you can only have one Accordion in the site. It would be better and more transparent that you can add multiple Accordion sections (making it a **block** in and of itself), with inner blocks of only one heading (the business team name) and multiple members.